# $\frac{\pi}{sin(a \pi)}=\frac{1}{a}+2a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-a^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Why does
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(a\pi\right)} =
\frac{1}{a} +
2a\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n + 1}}{n^{2} - 
a^{2}}
\quad\mbox{for}\ a >0\ \mbox{and}\ a\ \mbox{is not an}\ Integer.
$$
Why is this the case I've been trying to figure out why this is the case but can't make head or tail of it can anyone help $?$.

Comment: See [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem). This identity is a slightly more general form of [this special case](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Cosecant_Function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via a Fourier expansion of $\cos(\pi a x)$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, we can show that
$$
\cos(\pi a x) = \frac{\sin(a\pi)}{a\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{2a(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-a^2}\sin(\pi a)\cos(n \pi x)\,.
$$
This holds everywhere inside $(-1,1)$, so it holds in particular at $x=0$ where the cosine functions evaluate to 1, in which case this becomes
$$
1 = \frac{\sin(a\pi)}{a\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{2a(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-a^2}\sin(\pi a)\,.
$$
The result follows by multiplying both sides by $a\,/\sin(a\pi)$.